# Packed Bubble Art in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

Hi I am making a project in d3.js wherein I would intend to use d3.js to depict a packed bubble representation of the following image.

[image: parents image]

I intend to create a visualization which on hovering over a bubble will represent a pie chart.
Below are the examples of packed bubble representation.

[image: Flamingo]
[image: Elephant]

Please tell me how to create a packed bubble representation of the image in d3.js and how can I add a tooltip over the bubbles.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using Voronoi stippling for a grayscale image using d3.js but it is not looking aesthetic. Can't come up with an idea as to how to implement the packed bubble art since I am a newbie to d3.js and I am unable to find a resource.

Comment: "I tried using Voronoi stippling for a grayscale image using d3.js but it is not looking aesthetic" - post the code you tried ?